# MySQLi Prepared Statement Query Issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm relatively new to MySQLi prepared statements, and running into an error. Take this code:

```
$user = 'admin';
$pass = 'admin';

if ($stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$user' AND     password='$pass'"))
{
echo $stmt->num_rows;
}
```

This will display "1", as it should.

This next piece of code though, returns "0":

```
$user = 'admin';
$pass = 'admin';

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);
$stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->num_rows;
}
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call `store_result()` before you get the number of rows

```
$user = 'admin';
$pass = 'admin';
```

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();  // add this line
echo $stmt->num_rows;
}

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.

So execute() performs the query, but to access any results from the query I have to use store_result()? I've looked through the PHP MySQLi manual on this and it in't very clear (at least to me =P)

Comment: I know, I built an abstraction class around the mysqli object to make prepared statements a heck of alot easier then in the documentation

Comment: There's another gotcha too - you have to bind the results to a variable, so bind the paramaters, execute, bind the results